# IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite rule higher priority than folder

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, iis-7.5, asp.net-2.0

I have this rule in web.config.

```
<rule name="RewriteSourceCategorySuburb" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(news)$" />
  <conditions  logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?category={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The problem is I have the folder name called "**news**" in my root and it doesn't even have default.aspx in that folder but the web server is trying to view the folder "news" and shows this error "***403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.***" when I request **mysite.com/news**. Is it possible to make my rule to be processed higher than that folder name? Thanks.

Note: It is not just news folder it is happening all name with the same folders, I need to change a lot to rename those folders to something else. Please help. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue last month, and it ended up being an authentication setting within IIS. One thing you could check is the authentication settings in IIS, and change Anonymous Authentication to use the Application Pool Identity **instead of** the default, "IUSR".

You also need to have the URL rewrite module installed where your IIS is installed, here is a link http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: Thanks for that Gallen. I changed it to IUSR but it still doesn't work and still gives me 403 error.

Comment: You changed it _from_ IUSR, right? I'm updating my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: Yes please see this screen shot. http://i47.tinypic.com/23htvs9.jpg. I have URL rewrite module installed on my server and other rules are already working except this rule which has same name as the folder name.